# Nodejs/express best way to query MySQL data from client

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

What is the best way to query MySQL data from client (web browser) for Nodejs/Express project. 
I have database connection established in app.js file. That's starts when node is running. I also have an ejs file for front end. And want to be able to access data when button is clicked on the web page. I want to do it without leaving or re-loading the page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "What is the best way to query MySQL data from client (web browser) for Nodejs/Express project." the client (webbrowser) can use protocols like AJAX (with JSON), REST, SOAP, JSONP or websockets to fetch the data from the Node.js server... There is no "best" but AJAX (with JSON), REST, JSONP are designed to work fast.. Use Websockets when you need to have realtime updates. " I want to do it without leaving or re-loading the page" Then you need to use AJAX (with JSON) , or Websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people think of web-applications having three layers:

```
Frontend -> Browser
Backend  -> Express.js
Database -> MySQL
```

If you plan to transfer data from the Database to the frontend, this needs to go through the backend. As you have already noticed by setting up the db connection in express.

```
frontend
   |
backend
   |
database
```

So basically your backend can already talk to the database. You need to make the frontend to talk to the backend. In the context of a webapp, you are making a request. If you already have a page, and want to stay on that page, you need to do an ajax request (or fetch, the new kid in town) from the js running in the browser.